# jQuery positioning woes - can't accurately position element

Tags: jquery, positioning

I've been trying to position a #logo div at the center of a centered #content div using jQuery but results are inconsistent. Sometimes it works, other times not. In Safari on the iPad it often "fails" and the result is that the logo is placed under the menu which is of course not usable. Here's the central code:

```
function ReflowElements()
{
    var contentOffset = $("#content").offset();
    var contentWidth = $("#content").width();
    var menuWidth = $("#menu").width();

    var menuX = (contentOffset.left + contentWidth) - (menuWidth + 45);
    var menuY = contentOffset.top + 15;
    var menuPos = { left : menuX, top : menuY };

    var logoWidth = $("#logo").width();
    var logoX = (contentOffset.left + (contentWidth/2)) - (logoWidth/2);
    var logoY = menuY + 15;
    var logoPos = { left: logoX, top: logoY };

    $("#logo").offset(logoPos);
    $("#menu").offset(menuPos);
}
```

Site. http://restaurant-passagen.dk/

Any clues appreciated.

Comment: It's hard to say without looking at the specific code but two things spring to mind. 1) outerWidth might be what you're looking for, calculations using just width() may be innacurate. 2) width changes after $(document).ready, try $(window).load

Comment: I'm actually reflowing after the load event; also tried reflowing on setTimeout to see if that could be the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dude, CSS:

```
#logo {
    display:block; 
    margin:auto;
}
```

Comment: That's nice but I actually want to do this with jQuery scripting (don't ask :-)

Comment: Ok... you got me. What I meant was a "non 100% width"... And I assumed that #logo would be going on a div...